# SQL replase empty row to 0

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to get a list of locks on ORACLE. When there are no locks, an empty string is returned. How to make it output 0 if there are no rows, and output the required result if there are rows?

```
SELECT (b.seconds_in_wait) as TIME
FROM sys.v_$session b, sys.dba_blockers c, sys.dba_lock a
WHERE c.holding_session = a.session_id AND c.holding_session = b.sid and (username like '%MOBILE%');
```

I don't even know where to look for the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join your sql to a dummy row and handle null with Nvl() function

```sql
WITH
    dummy AS 
        ( Select 0 "DUMMY" From Dual),
    blocked AS 
        (   -- your SQL using Joins
            SELECT  b.SECONDS_IN_WAIT "A_TIME"
            FROM    sys.v_$session b  
            INNER JOIN sys.dba_lock a ON(a.SESSION_ID = b.SID)
            INNER JOIN sys.dba_blockers c ON(c.HOLDING_SESSION = b.SID)
            WHERE   b.username LIKE('%MOBILE%')         
        )
SELECT  Nvl(b.A_TIME, 0) "A_TIME"
FROM    dummy
LEFT JOIN blocked b ON(1 = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below by creating a virtual row using DUAL

```
 WITH SUB_QUERY AS(
 SELECT (b.seconds_in_wait) as TIME
 FROM sys.v_$session b, sys.dba_blockers c, sys.dba_lock a
 WHERE c.holding_session = a.session_id AND c.holding_session = b.sid 
 and(username like '%MOBILE%'))
 select * FROM SUB_QUERY
 union all
 select 0 FROM DUAL 
 where NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SUB_QUERY);
```

Comment: If this were for Production use I would probably put the driving query in a WITH clause and reference that in both the sub-queries, to remove the duplication of the logic.

Comment: @APC made the required corrections for better performance

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure the performance will be that different. It's more a matter of tidiness: having one copy of the logic rather than two is better for maintenance.

Comment: Please don't perpetuate the fallacy that using `,` for implicit join notation is acceptable.  It's been three ***decades*** since ANSI-92 `JOIN` syntax, it should ***always*** be used.

Comment: in case you may know oracle internally translates to , and (+) for joins in the ANSI syntax

Comment: @psaraj12 No, it doesn't. It's "translated" to an execution plan consisting of nested loops, mege joins, hash lookups, etc, etc. The sql syntax is a part of a declarative language which is then compiled to a proprietary plan. Stop spreading misinformation based on intuition and ignorance.

Comment: @MatBailie Please check the "access predicates" in the execution plan for better understanding.Stop spreading false propoganda

Comment: @psaraj12 Predicates (access, filter, or otherwise) have Zero relevance to "translate to `,` and `(+)`", stop talking shit.

Comment: @MatBailie IF you see the access predicates in the explain plan of OUTER JOIN you will see the use of (+) in them.I am not going to explain anymore.If you still think it is shit then i don't bother any more

Answer (score 0):

I would simply query the dual table and outer join the wait time query to it, like so:

```
WITH wait_time AS
 (SELECT (b.seconds_in_wait) AS TIME
  FROM   sys.v_$session   b,
       sys.dba_blockers c,
       sys.dba_lock     a
  WHERE  c.holding_session = a.session_id
  AND    c.holding_session = b.sid
  AND    (username LIKE '%MOBILE%'))
SELECT NVL(wt.time, 0)
FROM   dual
       LEFT OUTER JOIN wait_time wt ON 1=1;
```

That way, you'll always get at least one row returned, and you're only querying the wait time query once.

Comment: Please don't perpetuate the fallacy that using `,` for implicit join notation is acceptable.  It's been three ***decades*** since ANSI-92 `JOIN` syntax, it should ***always*** be used.

Comment: @MatBailie So sanctimonious. Simply because I took the query the OP provided as-is... did you miss the fact I used a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? Why are you not pointing this out to the OP instead of those of us who already use the ANSI join syntax?

Comment: No, I noticed, that doesn't justify inplace copying *(and implicit validation)* of the use of `,`

Comment: There is absolutely NOTHING incorrect about using the old-style join syntax. Sure, it's outdated and can't do things that the ANSI style joins can do with ease, but there's nothing implicitly wrong in using it. Stop demonising the old-style joins, because there's plenty of legacy code out there still using them, and we still need to know how to read it!